# An association between two Rails models which allows itself to be validated using validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Using Rails 3.2, not sure if that makes a difference

An `Owner` `has_many` `Bicycles`

I would like to place a limit on the number of `Bicycles` that an `Owner` can own, based on the value of the `bicycle_limit` field on the `Owner` model which stores the allowed limit for that Owner.

For now, I would like the `limit_bicycle_ownership` validation to run whenever a `Bicycle` or an `Owner` is validated/saved (and I will restrict it down later). To that end, I have placed `validates_associated: :owner` on the `Bicycle` model.

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bicycles, inverse_of: :owner

 validate :limit_bicycle_ownership

 def limit_bicycle_ownership
   if bicycles(:reload).size > bicycle_limit
     errors.add(:bicycles, "^Too many bicycles")
   end
 end
end

class Bicycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, inverse_of: :bicycles

  validates_presence :owner
  validates_associated: :owner
end
```

This setup behaves as expect when ownership of a bicycle is set or changed through an instance of the `Owner` model using:

```
owner = Owner.create(bicycle_limit: 1)
owner.bicycles << Bicycle.create()
owner.valid? # true
owner.bicycles << Bicycle.create()
owner.valid? # false
```

However, the validation does not seem to work when ownership is changed through an instance of the `Bicycle` model:

```
owner = Owner.create(bicycle_limit: 1)

bicycle1 = Bicycle.new(owner_id: owner.id)
bicycle1.valid? # true
owner.valid? # true
bicycle1.save! # true

bicycle2 = Bicycle.new(owner_id: owner.id)
bicycle2.valid? # true
owner.valid? # true
bicycle2.save! # true, but I was expecting this to fail
owner.valid? # false
```

I have pry'd into the `limit_bicycle_ownership` validation and as far as I can make out this is the process when bicycle2.save! is run:

- `bicycle2` knows enough about its new association with `owner` to validate it through the `validates_association :owner` callback
- `owner` however, does not appear to have any knowledge of the association which is now causing it to be validated, and `bicycles(:reload)` only returns the existing association with `bicycle1`
- The validation on `owner` then passes, because as far as `owner` is concerned, it only owns **one** bicycle (`bicycle1`) which does not exceed its `bicycle_limit` of 1
- `bicycle2` then continues validating and saving, and saves successfully, leaving `owner` owning two bicycles

So basically when setting or updating the owner of a bicycle, its new owner has no idea that the bicycle even exists until the bicycle has finished saving, by which time it is too late to perform a `validates_associated` call. Any ideas about a better way to do this, without having to duplicate the validation logic from the `Owner` model in the `Bicycle` model? I feel like there may be a solution involving an `after_save` callback on the `Bicycle` model, but I don't really know where to begin there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start a transaction when bycicle added to owner, if after adding owner is unvalid then rollback:

```
Bicycle.transaction do
  bicycle2 = Bicycle.new(owner_id: owner.id)
  bicycle2.valid? # true
  owner.valid? # true
  bicycle2.save!

  if !owner.valid?
   raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Error message..."
  end
end
```